# Vmware Player modules not saved into Ubuntu Kernel

Tags: 10.10, kernel, vmware, modules

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 with the 2.6.35-22.34-generic kernel and have the latest Vmware player installed, but each time I run Vmware Player it says it needs to load some modules into the running kernel. It does this every time I run Vmware player. It seems to install the modules OK as Vmware player runs after it's apparently installed the modules, but the modules aren't saved as it constantly keeps saying it needs to load modules.

Is there anyway to fix this, other than trying to go for a reinstall?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be related to the case of non-compilable VMCI Sock module (due to the changes in the kernel). Please see [this link](http://www.debuntu.org/how-wmware-workstation-7.1-ubuntu-maverick-meerkat-10.10) for the solution. Worked fine for me.

I've also had problems running VMWare Player after upgrading Ubuntu from 10.4 to 10.10 as it could not recompile it's modules (due to the changes in kernel) - [this guide](http://www.rrfx.net/2010/06/vmware-vmmon-module-compilation-issues.html) helped to solve that issue also.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the VMware Player modules to be loaded at boot in `/etc/modules`. This should save the hassle of loading them manually before running VMware Player.